# Как парсить данные с localhost:8080, используя Jsoup?

Tags: java, парсер, spring-boot, jsoup, vaadin

Имеется ли вообще такая возможность?
У меня есть 10 контейнеров с class="card", вот код:

```
try {
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://localhost:8080/configurator").get();
  Elements cards = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "card");
  System.out.println(cards.size());
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

По моей логике, должно выводить в консоль 10, но выводит 0. Соответственно, закрадываются подозрения, что код не особо работает :(

Comment: А если в браузере открыть страницу и посмотреть в консоли - может там вам контент отдельным запросом каким-то получается асинхронно?

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле всё оказалось немного сложней, т.к. я использую Vaadin, контент страницы формируется динамически на клиенте. К сожалению, JSoup не умеет работать с динамически формируемым контентом, отсюда и неправильный вывод. Возможно Selenium - то, что необходимо в таком случае.